# Basic algebra word problem: Number of sheep?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

A farmer raises sheep and chickens at his farm. The number of sheep is $\frac{1}{3}$ the number of chickens. There are $96$ fewer sheep legs than chicken legs. How many sheep are there at the farm?

My work:

Number of sheep = $S$

Number of Chickens = $C$

We know that there is one third of sheep than chickens. so, $\frac{1}{3}S = C$

We know that there are 96 fewer sheep legs than chicken leg. so, $2C = 4S - 96$

I got stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your first equation. If the number of sheep is $\frac{1}{3}$ the number of chicken then $3S = C$.

Also in your second equation, the $-$ needs to be a $+$ because if there are fewer sheep legs than chickens then you'll need to add 96 on the sheep value.

Then combine the equations and you'll get the answer.

Comment: Okay, after some time, I finally understand why you had to add the 96. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We know that there is one-third of sheep than chickens. so, $S=\frac{1}{3}C$

We know that there are 96 fewer sheep legs than the chicken leg. so,$ 2C-96=4S$

$$C=3S$$
$$2C-96=4S$$

Two equations two variables can you solve from here?

Comment: I'm not understanding why it's 2C - 96 = 4S?

I would expect 2C+96 = 4S

Comment: there are 96 fewer sheep legs than the chicken legs.


which means that sheep's legs are 96 less than that of cats 

cat has 2c legs sheep has 4S legs

Comment: I'm guessing the "than" makes the difference? so it means chicken legs is 96 less than sheep legs? Because I read it as sheep legs is 96 less than chicken legs.

Answer (score 1):

The number of sheep $S$ is $\frac{1}{3}$ the number of chickens $C$ so $S =\frac{1}{3}C $ and also $4S=2C - 96$
$$\begin{cases}
S=\frac{1}{3}C \\
4S=2C - 96
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
C=3S \\
4S=6S - 96
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
C=3S \\
2S= 96
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
C=3S \\
S= 48
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
C=144 \\
S= 48
\end{cases}$$

Comment: $$2c=4s+96 $$    look at your 2nd equation

Comment: Oh sure! I copied the same equations of the post and only corrected one, thanks!